# BS4 - returning 'None' when requesting Span

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have (another) quick question on BS4 when I am trying to take a price from a website.
A snippet of the html code is below:

```
        <div class="summary entry-summary col-md-7">
                            <h2 class="product_title entry-title">
        Tecsound SY50 Self Adhesive (7.26m2)    </h2>
<p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>61.50</bdi></span> <small class="woocommerce-price-suffix">(<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>73.80</bdi></span> inc vat)</small></p>
```

The price I am trying to get to is the £61.50 (which is the full price without GB taxes).

my attempt is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.the-website.co.uk")
vari = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(vari, "html.parser")
price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'woocommerce-Price-amount amount'})
print(price)
```

Output:

```
None
```

... and I have tried a similar:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url = requests.get("https://www.the-website.co.uk")
vari = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(vari, "html.parser")
span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'woocommerce-Price-amount amount'})
price = span.text
print(price)
```

this produces the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The second error is expected, as I am clearly not picking up the information with my request, so there is nothing or to show, or 'None' as shown in my first example.

Please can somebody help me to correctly pluck the information I require from the html text?

Comment: If the information is populated by Javascript after the page loads, you'd need to execute that Javascript to fetch the information. I believe Selenium is capable of that.

Comment: Try the function `print(vari)` to look to the request answer, then carefully look to it. You either need particular headers, or cookies for the request, or as @carcigenicate said, the information came lately with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Carcigenicate you should use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) - You also could improve your question by providing the real url.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

url = "https://soundproofingstore.uk/product/tecsound-sy50-self-adhesive/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)
sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'woocommerce-Price-amount amount'}).get_text()
print(price)

driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
£61.50
```